# Как можно скомпилить код на версии 3.4 не удаляя 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть необходимость пользоваться разными версиями Python 
И мне нужно с помощью pyinstaller скомпилить код
Но вот проблема в том что у меня стоит 2 разных версии Python(3.5 и 3.4)
И как можно скомпилить код на версии 3.4 не удаляя 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Попрубуй через Visual Studio Code + расширение Python, там можно выбрать через какую версию Python компилировать.
Upd: В левом нижнем углу.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, если работаете через командную строку.

1. Чтобы не было неоднозначностей при вызове python, в переменной окружения PATH лучше убрать путь к Python 3.4, оставить путь к Python 3.5
2. Создаем `python34.bat`, в него добавляем следующее содержимое:

   ```
   @c:\python34\python.exe %*
   ```

   `c:\python34` меняете на реальный путь к Python 3.4
3. В командной строке запускаем `python34 -m pip install pyinstaller` или если используете файл с зависимостями `requirements.txt`, то `python34 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`.
   Для удобства также можно создать файл `pip34.bat` со строкой `@python34 -m pip %*`
4. Создаем pyinstaller34.bat со следующим содержимым:

   ```
   @python34 -m pyinstaller %*
   ```

   После этого можно в командной строке запускать pyinstaller34 вместо pyinstaller, exe будет собираться с помощью Python 3.4

Полученные bat файлы нужно положить или в отдельную директорию, ее прописать в переменной окружения PATH, или положить непосредственно там, где нужно будет собирать exe файл.